# Colocar um array estado dentro de outro

Tags: javascript, react

Gostaria de saber como consigo colocar o **conteúdo** de um array que esteja com **status true** dentro de outro array, ficando por exemplo:
{ id:1, fruit:'Banana', status:true },
{ id:2, fruit:'Orange', status:true },
{ id:3, fruit:'Lemon', status:true }

Tentei fazer conforme o código abaixo, mas ele está colocando o item como array dentro do outro e não só o conteúdo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
const [fruits,setFruits] = useState([
    {
        id:1,
        fruit:'Banana',
        status:true,
    },
    {
        id:2,
        fruit:'Orange',
        status:true
    }
]);
const [newFruit, setNewFruit] = useState([
    {
        id:3,
        fruit:'lemon',
        status:true
    },
    {
        id:4,
        fruit:'morango',
        status:false
    }
]);
```

código JSX abaixo:

```
return (
    <div>
        {fruits.map((fruits,index)=>
            <span key={index}>{fruits.fruit}, </span>
        )
        }
        <button onClick={Add}>Adicionar</button>
    </div>
);
```

Função para adicionar nova fruta:

```
const Add = () =>{
    const filtered = newFruit.map((fruit)=>
        fruit.status === true 
        ?   {
                fruit
            }

        :   {
                
            }
    )
    
    setFruits([
        ...fruits,
        filtered
    ])
    console.log(fruits)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Basta desestruturar o *array* `filtered` como você fez com o *array* `fruits`:

```
setFruits([
    ...fruits,
    ...filtered
]);
```

Mas também tem o detalhe que esse array `filtered` não está sendo montado corretamente. Você está gerando ele com o método `map`, que gera um novo *array* com o mesmo tamanho do *array* em que ele foi chamado, e no seu código você está retornando um objeto vazio quando ele não passa pela sua condição `fruit.status === true`. Isso é desnecessário, você pode apenas utilizar o método `filter` para gerar um novo array:

```
const filtered = newFruit.filter((fruit) => fruit.status);

setFruits([
    ...fruits,
    ...filtered
]);
```

Comment: Opa, realmente ficou como eu esperava, não sabia que eu poderia destruturar o filtered tb. Muito obrigado!